# Implementing video chat and message chat at once android

Tags: android, video, chat, agora.io

I have done a lot of research, but couldn't find the answer. Currently I'm using agora.io.

What I mean :
I want to add into my android app voice call, but on the same screen.

It has to be possible write some messages during a call without ending it, like at this screen

[image]

Is it even possible to do it with agora.io or should I change the lib to another one?

Comment: Any solution found ?

Answer (score 0):

Agora video sdk can achieve that. You can use RTM sdk for messaging functionality and RTC sdk for video call. To put them in the same screen, you need to put the video ui on top of the messaging ui.

Comment: Have you some more informations about it? I'm not experienced android developer and this sounds like not an easy task.

Comment: you mean implementing these two (video + chat) splitting screen into two parts?

Comment: You can read this step-by-step tutorial for example:  https://medium.com/@shaocheng.yang1995/how-to-build-an-augmented-reality-remote-assistance-app-in-android-ffde6406dff5. Inside this article, i linked a demo app i created which contains both video and chat functionalities. Feel free to try this out and let me know if you have any questions. In the demo app, the video and chat are in different screens. You can put the video UI in the chat messaging UI to achieve having both functionalities in one screen.

Comment: Here are some documents that might be helpful to you as well: 
Agora API document: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/index.html. 
Agora Video Call QuickStart Guide in Android:
https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_android?platform=Android

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you a lot! In case of questions or problems I'm going to ask

Comment: @ShaochengYang, how to achieve 1) the both video and text chat in the same screen and 2) sometimes  only video chat depending on the users choice in Flutter ? Any guideline ? 3) Is there any special name for such a screen where both text and video chat exist ?